# Rust Wasm and webpack-dev-server 5: Module not found

Tags: webpack, rust, webpack-dev-server, rust-wasm

I'm trying to write [hello, world](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html) with rust and wasm. Dev server works with

```
"webpack": "^4.29.3", 
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
```

but if update to

```
"webpack": "^5.90.3", 
"webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.2"
```

`Module not found` error occurs after rebuilding wasm.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `git clone https://github.com/levap5/wasm-game-of-life.git`
2. `cd wasm-game-of-life`
3. `git checkout 90666d3f`
4. `wasm-pack build`
5. `cd www`
6. `npm install`
7. `npm run start` | webpack-dev-server will start. There are no errors now.
8. open http://localhost:8080/ It works as expected
9. change alert message in `src/lib.rs`
10. `wasm-pack build` in `wasm-game-of-life` dir

The error occurs after step 10 and `http://localhost:8080/` runs old (cached) rust (wasm) code. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [wasm-pack-plugin](https://github.com/wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin) plugin.

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    // ...
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const WasmPackPlugin = require("@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin");
// ...
plugins: [
    new WasmPackPlugin({
      crateDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, "..") // ".." in my case
    }),
   // ...
]
// ...
```

However, the plugin's maintenance is questionable. I immediately came across [this issue](https://github.com/wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin/issues/93). After looking at the plugin code, the issue seems easy to fix.